# C# do while loop not working

Tags: c#, do-while

Making a program that i want to loop (for school so its basic) until they input 167. Heres what i got so far but its not working:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        { }
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to this swedish sauna!");
        Console.Write("Please enter the desired temperature: ");
        double fahrenheit = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        double celsius = FahrToCels(fahrenheit);
        bool stop = false;
        do
            if (celsius > 77)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The temperature {0}°C is too high, the highest acceptable temperature is 170°F (77°C).", celsius);
                Console.Write("Please re-enter the temperature that you wish to have: ");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (celsius < 73)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The temperature {0}°C is too low, the lowest acceptable temperature is 163°F (73°C).", celsius);
                Console.Write("Please re-enter the temperature that you wish to have: ");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        while (celsius == 75);

            { 
            stop = true;

  Console.WriteLine("You have reached the optimal temperature of the sauna. No more adjustments needed.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    public static double FahrToCels(double fahr)
    {

        double temp = (fahr - 32) * 5 / 9;
        return temp;
```

I cant get the loop to work properly, what am i missing?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it is not working? Generally the loop works how it is supposed to. It will act in the way that you programmed it to.

Comment: I don't see any loop here that waits for the value `167` in any fashion. The only loop in your code will continue looping _only_ if the `celsius` variable is set to `75`. Why do you expect any other behavior? The question is not clear at all...please explain in more detail why you think the code should do what you claim it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having with it not looping is becuase your "while" line should read "while (celsius != 75);" instead of "while (celsius == 75);". The next issue is you have is that when the console is reading the line you are not assigning that variable to the celsius variable so the last variable is getting stuck and not changing.